# Font-face not working IE7/IE 8

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I want to add a font to a site, but I can't make it work in IE7 and IE8.
It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE 9. I have tried some solutions I found but none of them work.
I tried this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyriadPro-SemiboldCond';
src: url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.woff') format('woff'), url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Also tried this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyriadPro-SemiboldCond';
src: url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.eot');
src: url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/static/fonts/MyriadPro-SemiboldCond.svg#MyriadPro-SemiboldCond') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

It looks good to me, but obviusly I am missing something. I don't know if the font I am using "MyriadPro" is the problem.

Is there another way of doing this in IE7/IE8? The javascript solutions like cufon make the text unselectable.

Comment: Are you using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ ?

Comment: How is your folders set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in IE7&8 but if there is a problem like this happening then you should look into another option like [googlefonts](http://www.google.com/fonts)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DroidSansMono';
src: url('../fonts/droid_sans_mono_regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/droid_sans_mono_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/droid_sans_mono_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/droid_sans_mono_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/droid_sans_mono_regular-webfont.svg#DroidSansMono') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Using google fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash|Press+Start+2P' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Comment: I was able to solve it, my font was corrupted and ie wasn't able to read it correctly, I used FontForge to slove it. Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: No problem! I apologize that I couldn't have been of more help but I am glad to hear you resolved it.